# Sentry: Unable to use regexes as networkDetailAllowUrls parameters

Tags: regex, sentry

I'm using sentry in my typescript saas that I've developer.

When initializing Sentry, I add the following parameters (https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/session-replay/configuration/):

networkDetailAllowUrls
networkRequestHeaders
networkResponseHeaders
networkCaptureBodies

Since my SaaS has both a production and a test environment, I need to validate two different API endpoints.
https://api.staging.eu
https://api.production.eu

As a result, I need to use two regex patterns to monitor these two URLs in all their variations.
Therefore, I have set up the regex patterns as you can see below.

```
    integrations: [new BrowserTracing(), new Sentry.Replay({
        [...]
        networkDetailAllowUrls: [window.location.origin, '^https:\/\/api\.staging\.eu(\/.*)?$', '^https:\/\/api\.production\.eu(\/.*)?$'],
        networkRequestHeaders: ["Cache-Control"],
        networkResponseHeaders: ["Referrer-Policy"],
        networkCaptureBodies: true,
    },)],
```

The problem is that these regex patterns don't seem to be working because for each issue monitored by Sentry, it tells me to add the specific API URL in order to be able to control it.

> Add https://api.staging.eu/tenant/admin/.... to your
> networkDetailAllowUrls list to start capturing data.

So I was wondering what I might be doing wrong. I tried the regex patterns on an online validator, and they work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if the backslash is required before the forward slashes.

The patterns are valid, though, and work for the provided values.

```
^https://api\.staging\.eu(?:/.*)?$
^https://api\.production\.eu(?:/.*)?$
```

Or

```
^https://api\.(?:staging|production)\.eu(?:/.*)?$
```